# Yocto Project for a New Board

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded, yocto, u-boot

I am trying to hunt down specifics on Yocto in regards to how to set up the filesystem before the build of poky.

I have a new board that I wanted to try Yocto on.

I have this FS so far after `source oe-init-build-env` in the /poky/ directory.

It goes:

`/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/conf/machine/include/SomeFile.inc`

In `/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/`, I have some loose files floating w/ `.dts` and `.dtsi` suffixes and a `/conf/` dir.

In `/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/conf/`, I have a `layer.conf` and `/machine/` dir.

In `/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/conf/machine/`, there is a `beaglev-fire.conf` file and an `/include/` dir.

```
So far, the errors are irrelevant to me...

As I have not been able to make it past the errors from:
```

`bitbake MACHINE=beaglev-fire core-image-full-cmdline`

So, in `/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/conf/machine/include/`, I have an `.inc` file for booting into u-boot.

Anyway...

I am reading manuals and tutorials but need an extra guide on this venture. C & P will not work as far as I can tell. Also, is there some template somewhere online that you know of currently that can take some guesswork out of the FS of Yocto builds?

There are some particulars b/c of the Microchip PolarFire SOC used on this specific board that have to do w/ pre-u-boot transfers. Anyway, here is `beaglev-fire.conf` from `/poky/meta-beaglev-fire/meta-start/conf/machine/`.

```
#@TYPE: Machine 
#@NAME: icicle-kit-es 
#@SOC: Polarfire SoC 
#@DESCRIPTION: Machine configuration for the Microchip Polarfire SoC, Icicle Kit Engineering Sample 
require include/mpfs-common.inc 
MACHINE_TYPE = "smp" 
RISCV_SBI_FDT ?=  "mpfs-beaglev-fire.dtb" 
KERNEL_DTC_FLAGS += "-@" 
KERNEL_DEVICETREE ?= "microchip/${RISCV_SBI_FDT}" 
UBOOT_CONFIG = "mpfs_icicle" 
UBOOT_CONFIG[mpfs_] = "microchip_mpfs_icicle_defconfig" 
## Set this to "mmc-tftp" to generate a boot.scr file which should be included 
##  in the boot partition. It will try to load a kernel image from mmc and fall back to tftp 
UBOOT_ENV = "tftp-mmc" 
HSS_PAYLOAD = "uboot" 
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES ?= " \ 
    fitImage \ 
    boot.scr.uimg \ 
" 
WKS_FILE ?= "mpfs-rootfs.wks" 
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "icicle-kit:"
```

I mean...do I have control over the `menuconfig` utility at all w/ Yocto?